# Checkbox in SQL 2012

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox

I created a web form using asp.net and connect it to the table in SQL2012.
I insert data to table with parameters in asp. Everything is ok but the checkboxes in the form, always pass false to the table and in the sql they data are always false (it's not different that they are checked or not, they pass false).
The columns in sql have "bit" datatype for these checkboxes.
Here is the code:

```
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@host", host.Checked);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domain", domain.Checked);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@needContent", needContent.Checked);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CMS", CMS.Checked);
```

ASP.net Code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="host" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="domain" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="domain" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CMS" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Why you have 2 checkboxes with same ID `domain`?

Comment: And your question is...? Anyway, you have to provide more code if you want us to analyse your problem.

Comment: What does your `INSERT` statement look like?

Comment: You're passing the data to the database incorrectly. So the database never saves it properly, hence always seeing false. This has nothing to do with SQL 2012, everything to do with your code

Comment: user3036342 - what is incorrect in this code?

Comment: Can you please edit the question? There is nothing called checkbox in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Aboved Code looks works fine for me, even though Please find one more solution for you approach here.

```
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@host", host.Checked==true?1:0);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domain", domain.Checked==true?1:0);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@needContent", domain.Checked==true?1:0);
cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CMS", CMS.Checked==true?1:0);
```